# How do I find the smallest sample space for two random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am working on this problem where a person with a gun has three actions - hit, miss, abstain. He shoots twice.

The sample space, S, should then be = ${[H,A,M]}^2 $.

Now, what should be the smallest sample space which can be made when hitting(H) and abstaining(A) are random variables. I tried to work this out on my own, but I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: What do you mean by "hitting and abstaining are random variables"?  Do you mean that when the person hits or abstains, a random quantity in some subset of the real numbers is generated, and this should be part of the outcome?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry for not framing it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample space consists of all possible outcomes (or at least all parts of the outcomes that are relevant to whatever we're trying to do).  So in this case it seems $S = S_1^2$ where $S_1$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb R$ (or some subsets thereof, where your random variables take values) corresponding to H and A, and one point corresponding to M.

Comment: Hey, I got it now. Thanks for explaining!